# MySQL select of record with latest date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables: COURSES and PERMISSIONS. I'm trying to do a `SELECT` that shows the latest permission value for all existing courses of a given student, in a given account.

Right now, I do this:

```
SELECT COURSES.NAME, PERMISSIONS.VALUE, PERMISSIONS.TS
FROM COURSES LEFT JOIN PERMISSIONS
ON PERMISSIONS.C_ID = COURSES.C_ID AND PERMISSIONS.S_ID = '12345'
WHERE COURSES.A_ID = 'ABCDE'
```

The result I get is

```
NAME          |  VALUE  |   TS
-----------------------------------------------
Mathematics   | 1       | 2012-01-19 19:13:21
Mathematics   | 0       | 2012-01-19 19:13:15
Mathematics   | 0       | 2012-01-19 19:20:19
Mathematics   | 0       | 2012-01-19 19:20:27
Mathematics   | 0       | 2012-01-19 19:21:29
Biology       |         |
```

What I need is to show only the record with the latest timestamp (TS) so it shows this:

```
NAME          |  VALUE  |   TS
-----------------------------------------------
Mathematics   | 0       | 2012-01-19 19:21:29
Biology       |         |
```

I tried `GROUP BY` on the course name in conjunction with an `ORDER BY` on the timestamp but it didn't pick up the correct record.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COURSES.NAME, PL.VALUE, PL.TS
FROM COURSES
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT 
       PERMISSIONS.C_ID, PERMISSIONS.VALUE, PERMISSIONS.TS
    FROM PERMISSIONS
    JOIN
      ( SELECT P.C_ID, MAX(P.TS) AS LATEST
        FROM PERMISSIONS P
        WHERE P.S_ID = '12345'
        GROUP BY P.C_ID ) PG
    ON PERMISSIONS.TS = PG.LATEST ) PL
  ON PL.C_ID = COURSES.C_ID
WHERE COURSES.A_ID = 'ABCDE'
```

Depending on the size of your data you might consider adding an index on (C_ID,TS) for PERMISSIONS table to speed up finding latest date:

```
ALTER TABLE `PERMISSIONS` ADD INDEX (`C_ID`,`TS`);
```

Comment: Worked great! Got me on the right track. Added to the second sub-`SELECT` a `WHERE PERMISSIONS.S_ID = '12345'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use HAVING. So it should go by something like this

```
SELECT COURSES.NAME, PERMISSIONS.VALUE, PERMISSIONS.TS
FROM COURSES LEFT JOIN PERMISSIONS
ON PERMISSIONS.C_ID = COURSES.C_ID AND PERMISSIONS.S_ID = '12345'
WHERE COURSES.A_ID = 'ABCDE'
GROUP BY COURSES.A_ID
HAVING PERMISSIONS.TS = MAX(PERMISSIONS.TS)
```

(it would be easier with the tables structures)

Another possibility is to think it the opposite way. Join the PERMISSIONS table on itself and find the permission that doesn't have a higher timestamp

```
   SELECT COURSES.NAME, PA.VALUE, PA.TS
    FROM COURSES LEFT JOIN PERMISSIONS PA
    ON PA.C_ID = COURSES.C_ID AND PA.S_ID = '12345'
    WHERE COURSES.A_ID = 'ABCDE' 
        AND (PA.C_ID == NULL || NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * 
            FROM PERMISSIONS PB
            WHERE PA.C_ID = PB.C_ID AND PB.S_ID = '12345' AND PB.TS > PA.TS))
```

Comment: I tried both options but the result isn't as expected. The HAVING option for example returns no records.

Comment: Mmhh there may be an error in the HAVING. In the other, what problem are you seeing? Multiple Mathematics lines or no Biology (actually, yes, I am missing the null case)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative - with a subselect computing the maximum timestamps of permission table:

```
SELECT courses.name, x.value, x.timestamp
FROM courses 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT p1.c_id, p1.s_id, p1.value, p1.timestamp
    FROM permissions p1 
    LEFT JOIN permissions p2 ON p1.c_id = p2.c_id AND p1.s_id = p2.s_id AND p1.timestamp < p2.timestamp
    WHERE p2.timestamp IS NULL) x ON courses.c_id = x.c_id AND x.s_id = '12345'
WHERE courses.a_id = 'ABCDE'
```