# MySql Record Matching Criteria With Latest Date

Tags: mysql

I have a mySql table where all status changes are recorded.  I want to be able to query the status of all items on a specific date, or the last date for all items.  The table I have now is:

```
CREATE TABLE `tra_rel_sta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tra_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sta_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `changed_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tra_id` (`tra_id`),
  KEY `rel` (`tra_id`,`sta_id`,`changed_on`),
  KEY `sta_id` (`sta_id`),
  KEY `changed_on` (`changed_on`),
  KEY `tra_changed` (`tra_id`,`changed_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51734 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(I know I'm probably overdoing the indexes, but I haven't exactly figured out how to optimize indexes yet).

The query I'm using now, which works is:

```
SELECT rel.changed_on, rel.changed_by, rel.tra_id, sta.id AS sta_id, sta.status, sta.description, sta.onHold, sta.awaitingApproval, sta.approved, sta.complete, sta.locked
FROM ( 
    SELECT tra_id, MAX(changed_on) AS lst
    FROM tra_rel_sta 
    GROUP BY tra_id
) AS rec
LEFT JOIN tra_rel_sta AS rel ON rel.changed_on = rec.lst AND rel.tra_id = rec.tra_id
LEFT JOIN tra_status AS sta ON sta.id = rel.sta_id
```

If I want to use a specific date, I insert a WHERE statement in the sub-query.

This works, but it takes about 0.65 seconds to run in PHP with about 51,733 records in the table. This query is used as a sub query in several others when I need to know the last status of an object, and as a result, is slowing down many application.

I've tried to use a sub query in the WHERE statement as described in [MySQL: how to select record with latest date before a certain date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893234/mysql-how-to-select-record-with-latest-date-before-a-certain-date) but it takes almost twice as long.    I've tried using a JOIN statement as described in [MySQL select of record with latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948949/mysql-select-of-record-with-latest-date) but I'm getting about the same or just slightly slower results.

How can I optimize this query or fix my indexes to make this more effective?

Thanks!!

As requested, EXPLAIN of query:

```
id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                     | key     | key_len | ref               | rows  | Extra
---|-------------|-------------|--------|-----------------------------------|---------|---------|-------------------|-------|-------------
1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | ALL    | NULL                              | NULL    | NULL    | NULL              | 49931 | NULL
1  | PRIMARY     | rel         | ref    | tra_id,rel,changed_on,tra_changed | tra_id  | 5       | rec.tra_id        | 1     | Using where
1  | PRIMARY     | sta         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY | 4       | csinfo.rel.sta_id | 1     | NULL
2  | DERIVED     | tra_rel_sta | index  | tra_id,rel,tra_changed            | tra_id  | 5       | NULL              | 49931 | NULL
```

Comment: Post the `EXPLAIN` of your posted query as well

Comment: Do you have an index on table `tra_rel_stat` for `tra_Id, changed_on, and sta_id`

Comment: I have one for tra_id, sta_id, changed_on ... slightly different order.  I tried based on your comment changing the order of the index, but it did not seem to have an affect on the speed.

Comment: What version of mysql?  8.0 supports CTE.  If that's too bleeding edge for you, then you're stuck with a view or a copy of the table to do the equivalent.

Comment: I'm using version 5.6.27.  I'm self taught, and have no idea what CTE is.